# Compute limit with continuous function $f$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Problem :** Let $f\colon[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous function.

Compute $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}+\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}+\cdots+\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})}{x_n-x_{n-1}}}{n}$$

Where $a<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{n-1}<x_n<b$

---

I tried $y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$ Then $y_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ and the limit becomes to :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(x_{k-1}+y_k)-f(x_{k-1})}{y_k}$$

and this has similar form with derivative.

But there was no result and I don't know $f$ is differentiable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the function $f$, or on the distribution of the $x_k$ (e.g. equidistant)?

Comment: Shouldn't it be that $x_1 = a$ and a requirement that $x_n \to b$ as $n \to \infty$? Otherwise, any answer would have to be given in terms of $x_1$ and $\lim_n x_n$. Also, your summation should be of $\dfrac{f(x_k + y_k) - f(x_k)}{y_k}$, not with $k-1$.

Comment: Also $y_k=x_{k+1}-x_k \to 0$ does not follow from the problem statement, you might want to *require* that $\max_k (x_{k+1} - x_k)$ converges to zero.